# Multiple updates on MySQL without overwriting data

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using a jQuery sortable to sort the rows of my table. The new order gets saved in the backend and I am using python, Django. I have a column in my database called `priority.`

This is how I handle the logic in the backend. the last array is a 2D list Basically, I want the following to happen:

```
previous_order = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
new_order = [3,4,5,1,2]

orders_to_rearrange = [                  ### gets passed in a function
    [1,3], [2,4], [3,5], [4,1], [5,2]
]

### UPPDATE the following:
### Priority 1 to become 3
### Priority 2 to become 4
### Priority 3 to become 5
### Priority 4 to become 1
### Priority 5 to become 1
```

The above is a pretty example, but when I encounter a complicated switch like this:

```
### Priority 5 to become 2
### Priority 2 to become 4
### Priority 4 to become 1
```

Notice how after 5 becomes 2, 4 becomes 2 and so did the previous 5. Now I end up having two priority 2 because it overwrites the statement inside the loop.

I though that the WHEN THEN case statement in MySQL will help, but it ends up doing the same thing as I loop.

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET priority = 
        CASE priority
        %s
        ELSE priority
END
```

note: I have a function that converts my 2D array into a WHEN __ THEN __ statement and will replace that %s pattern.

Can anyone please give me an advise on how to update rows simultaneously in a single statement and without overwriting data?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by updating rows without overwriting data but I think you might have been on the right track with using a case statement...at least as far as I understood the problem. `update my_table
   set priority = case when priority = 1 then 3
            when priority = 2 then 4
            when priority = 3 then 5
             when priority = 4 then 1
            when priority = 5 then 1 else priority end
 where priority > 0;`.

Comment: Hi @JuveLeo1906 will this get executed line by line or all at the same time? For some reason, when I refresh my page, the order does not get saved accordingly. I don't know where in my UPDATE statement is breaking..

Comment: It would be updated all at the same time since it's one statement.  Perhaps you're missing a commit statement before refreshing the page?

Comment: I think I just realized what the problem is. When my page reloads, the new order is sorted in ASC order. Therefore, no matter how I sort these things, they will show up in order. In this case, do you know how I can see the new priority that is not in Order? @JuveLeo1906

Comment: Ahh, sure you can simple select the data without ordering, it should work.  Another easy way would be to have an auto_increment pkey in your table and order by that: `create table my_table(id int(11) auto_increment
          , priority int(2)
          , primary key id_pkey(id));`

Comment: @JuveLeo1906 Got it! thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might just be a matter of fixing the case statement...unless I didn't understand the problem correctly:

```
update my_table
   set priority = case when priority = 1 then 3
                       when priority = 2 then 4
                       when priority = 3 then 5
                       when priority = 4 then 1
                       when priority = 5 then 1
                       else priority end
 where priority > 0;
```